# htaccess redirect http to https but not for cloudflare

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, cloudflare

I have an apache server that responds to two type of websites , one type is served trough cloudflare and other sites are served directly from the server.

I need to do a test in htaccess in order to detect if client/visitor is cloudflare and NOT redirect `http` to `https` if it is a cloudflare request.

Because I understand cloudflare makes all requests to server (ip) over `http` even thou it shows `https` in browser, and redirecting that to `https` creates an infinite loop.

I tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTP_CDN_LOOP} !cloudflare
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

**EDIT:** correct variable is `%{HTTP:CDN-LOOP}`, will add an answer.

It fails and it creates an infinite loop, because it also redirects to https when request is made by cloudflare. Maybe `%{ENV:HTTP_CDN_LOOP}` is wrong in `htaccess` enviroment, I am not sure how to translate the variables, these are the relevant variables I see in PHP `$_SERVER`:

```
[HTTP_CDN_LOOP] => cloudflare
[HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO] => https
[HTTP_CF_RAY] => 76abb80fdef4etz5-FOO
[HTTP_CF_VISITOR] => {"scheme":"http"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question, since I know I will run into this again and find my answer :)

Correct variable format for `htaccess` is `%{HTTP:CDN-LOOP}` so full code to redirect only non-Cloudlfare requests to https would be:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CDN-LOOP} !cloudflare
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

**Note1:** by default, cloudflare makes requests to server over HTTP port 80 connecting to IP. If you redirect ALL http requests to https (without above condition), the cloudflare requests can cause infinite loop.

**Note2:** even if you add above condition, the end user (in browser) can still see http address. In cloudflare control panel enable "Always Use HTTPS" for the browser address to always be https.